# OAuth with KeyCloak in Ktor : Is it supposed to work like this?

Tags: kotlin, authentication, oauth-2.0, keycloak, ktor

I tried to set up a working Oauth2 authorization via Keycloak in a Ktor web server. The expected flow would be sending a request from the web server to keycloak and logging in on the given UI, then Keycloak sends back a code that can be used to receive a token. Like [here](https://www.appsdeveloperblog.com/keycloak-authorization-code-grant-example/)

First I did it based on the examples in Ktor's documentation. [Oauth](https://ktor.io/docs/oauth.html#example) It worked fine until it got to the point where I had to receive the token, then it just gave me HTTP status 401. Even though the curl command works properly. Then I tried an example project I found on [GitHub](https://github.com/imalik8088/ktor-starter) , I managed to make it work by building my own HTTP request and sending it to the Keycloak server to receive the token, but is it supposed to work like this?

I have multiple questions regarding this.

1. Is this function supposed to handle both authorization and getting the token?

   ```
    authenticate(keycloakOAuth) {
        get("/oauth") {
            val principal = call.authentication.principal<OAuthAccessTokenResponse.OAuth2>()

            call.respondText("Access Token = ${principal?.accessToken}")
        }
    }
   ```
2. I think my configuration is correct, since I can receive the authorization, just not the token.

   ```
   const val KEYCLOAK_ADDRESS = "**"

   val keycloakProvider = OAuthServerSettings.OAuth2ServerSettings(
   name = "keycloak",
   authorizeUrl = "$KEYCLOAK_ADDRESS/auth/realms/production/protocol/openid-connect/auth",
   accessTokenUrl = "$KEYCLOAK_ADDRESS/auth/realms/production/protocol/openid-connect/token",
   clientId = "**",
   clientSecret = "**",
   accessTokenRequiresBasicAuth = false,
   requestMethod = HttpMethod.Post, // must POST to token endpoint
   defaultScopes = listOf("roles")
   )
   const val keycloakOAuth = "keycloakOAuth"

    install(Authentication) {
        oauth(keycloakOAuth) {
        client = HttpClient(Apache)
        providerLookup = { keycloakProvider }
        urlProvider = { "http://localhost:8080/token" }
    }
   }
   ```
3. There is this /token route I made with a built HTTP request, this one manages to get the token, but it feels like a hack.

   ```
   get("/token"){
    var grantType = "authorization_code"
    val code = call.request.queryParameters["code"]
    val requestBody = "grant_type=${grantType}&" +
            "client_id=${keycloakProvider.clientId}&" +
            "client_secret=${keycloakProvider.clientSecret}&" +
            "code=${code.toString()}&" +
            "redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/token"

    val tokenResponse = httpClient.post<HttpResponse>(keycloakProvider.accessTokenUrl) {
        headers {
            append("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        }
        body = requestBody
    }
    call.respondText("Access Token = ${tokenResponse.readText()}")
   }
   ```

TL;DR: I can log in via Keycloak fine, but trying to get an access_token gives me 401. Is the authenticate function in ktor supposed to handle that too?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer to your first question: it will be used for both if that route corresponds to the redirect URI returned in `urlProvider` lambda.

The overall process is the following:

1. A user opens http://localhost:7777/login (any route under `authenticate`) in a browser
2. Ktor makes a redirect to `authorizeUrl` passing necessary parameters
3. The User logs in through Keycloak UI
4. Keycloak redirects the user to the redirect URI provided by `urlProvider` lambda passing parameters required for acquiring an access token
5. Ktor makes a request to the token URL and executes the routing handler that corresponds to the redirect URI (http://localhost:7777/callback in the example).
6. In the handler you have access to the `OAuthAccessTokenResponse` object that has properties for an access token, refresh token and any other parameters returned from Keycloak.

Here is the code for the working example:

```
val provider = OAuthServerSettings.OAuth2ServerSettings(
    name = "keycloak",
    authorizeUrl = "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/auth",
    accessTokenUrl = "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/$realm/protocol/openid-connect/token",
    clientId = clientId,
    clientSecret = clientSecret,
    requestMethod = HttpMethod.Post // The GET HTTP method is not supported for this provider
)

fun main() {
    embeddedServer(Netty, port = 7777) {
        install(Authentication) {
            oauth("keycloak_oauth") {
                client = HttpClient(Apache)
                providerLookup = { provider }
                // The URL should match "Valid Redirect URIs" pattern in Keycloak client settings
                urlProvider = { "http://localhost:7777/callback" }
            }
        }

        routing {
            authenticate("keycloak_oauth") {
                get("login") {
                    // The user will be redirected to authorizeUrl first
                }

                route("/callback") {
                    // This handler will be executed after making a request to a provider's token URL.
                    handle {
                        val principal = call.authentication.principal<OAuthAccessTokenResponse>()

                        if (principal != null) {
                            val response = principal as OAuthAccessTokenResponse.OAuth2
                            call.respondText { "Access token: ${response.accessToken}" }
                        } else {
                            call.respondText { "NO principal" }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }.start(wait = false)
}
```